# UnitTesting: how to pass my mock class in the read code

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, oop, mockito

I am using hazelcast in my project and I want to unit test some function but i do not want it to connect to real hazelcast and perform test on it for that i created a custom mock class which simply uses scala map because in hazelcast maps also there 
here is my code

```
trait UserRepository {
  def getUserObj(id: String):Option[User] 
  def addToUserRepo(user: User)
}

class UserRepo extends UserRepository{
  def getUserObj(id: String):Option[User]  = {
    val userMap = hcastClient.getMap[String, User]("UserMap")
    val userObj = userMap.get(id)
    Option(userObj)
  }
def addToUserRepo(user: User) = {
    val directUserMap: IMap[String, User] = hcastClient.getMap[String,User]("UserMap")
    directUserMap.set(user.uuid, user)
  }
```

and here i created a simple customized mocked version class where the functionality is same just; replaced it with scala map:

```
class UserRepoMock extends UserRepository {
  val map:Map[String,User]=Map[String,User]()
  def getUserMap:Map[String,User] = {
    map
  }

  def getUserObj(id: String):User  = {
    val userMap = getUserMap
    val userObj = userMap.get(id)
    userObj
  }
  def addToUserRepo(user: User) = {
    val userMap = getUserMap
    userMap.put(user.uuid, user)
  }

class UserUtil(userRepo:UserRepo) {
def addUser(user:User):Boolean={
 try{
   userRepo.addToUserRepo(user)
   true
 }
catch {
 case e:Exception=>false
}
def getUser(id:String):User={
   val user=userRepo.getUserObj(id)
   user
}
```

Mow i want to unit test methods `addUser` and `getUser`of `UserUtil` class
by doing like this:

```
class UserUtilTest extends funSpec {
     val userUtil=new UserUtil(new UserRepoMock)
        userUtil.addUser //perform unit test on it 
        userUtil.getUser //perform unit test on it
        // instead of doing this val userUtil=new UserUtil(new UserRepo)
}
```

but the compiler not allowing me to do that,there is something which i am missing, Please help me how can i achieve the desired functionality

This is the compiler error:

```
type mismatch; found : testhcastrepo.UserRepoMock required: com.repositories.UserRepo
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve] ... hint: error message!

Comment: edited the question i have mentioned the error  please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well: your utils class says:

```
class UserUtil(userRepo:UserRepo)
```

So it needs an instance of **UserRepo**.

But then your are passing an instance of **UserRepoMock**. A UserRepoMock is a UserRepository, as UserRepo is; but a UserRepoMock **is not** a UserRepo!

Probably it is as simple as changing the utils to

```
class UserUtil(userRepo:UserRepository)
```

to indicate that you don't want to specify a specific **class**. Instead you simply say: anything that has the *trait* will do!

Beyond that: the *real* answer might be: have a look at your **naming** habits. You see, those two names **UserRepositor** and **UserRepo**; they are pretty "close" to each other; and it is *not at all* clear, what the difference between the two is. If the names would be more distinct, like **UserRepositoryTrait** and **HCastUserRepository** you probably would not have made this mistake in the first place (not sure my suggestions are "good" names according to scala conventions; but they are just meant to give you an idea).

Comment: thank you so much very basic thing that i was missing